# Does iOS MDM permit developers to deploy "development certificate" / development applications to iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mdm

When using an MDM solution to restrict users from installing applications on iOS/iPhone, are there any provisions/configurations that would allow iPhone developers to install their app under development on the phone with MDM enabled and still restricting other applications installs?

Comment: The first question to ask, is are the devices supervised (enrolled in DEP or set up with Apple Configurator)?  If they are, then if you are blacklisting you can install any apps that aren't blacklisted. If you are whitelisting then the bundle ids of any apps that you are developing would need to be included in the whitelist or (probably better) just exclude the app whitelisting payload from development device profiles.

Comment: So to clarify what you're saying, if the device is enrolled in DEP or Apple Configurator, then the apps being developed can be whitelisted to allow developers to install directly?

Comment: Kind of; device supervision (either via DEP or Apple Configurator) is a prerequisite for app black/white listing.  If your device isn't supervised then there are no restrictions on what apps can/can't be installed.  If your device is supervised then if a whitelisting policy is deployed then only bundle IDs in the profile can be installed; regardless of whether that installation is from the App Store or Xcode.  If a blacklisting policy is installed then any bundle IDs not included in the policy can be installed.